# How to use timezone.now() in django with activate timezone?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django 3.2 and changed my `setting.py` as

```py
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

and try to use `timezone.now()` It gives me the UTC time when I print it from my `view.py` It worked well for `DateTimeField` in models when I store some data into it. I also activate the timezone

```py
from django.utils.timezone import activate
activate(settings.TIME_ZONE)
```

I don't know why it works for models but not for view. Can anybody explain how to use timezone in django.

```
datetime.datetime.now() # 2022-08-29 02:03:44.941847
timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) # 2022-08-29 02:03:44.941847+05:30
timezone.now() # 2022-08-28 20:33:44.941847+00:00
timezone.get_current_timezone() # Asia/Kolkata
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to run in your view?

Comment: I am only returning `HttpResponse(timezone.now())`.

Comment: Is it always required to use `localtime` to get time according to our timezone?